# How to enter a custom server

Tags: rust

How do you enter a server by IP address?  I have tried many things already for hours at a time looking for the custom server entry field.

Answer (score 3):

You have two main options that I know of:

In game, press F1 and enter: `net.connect 000.000.000.000:00000`

Use a Steam link in a browser, such as: `steam://connect/000.000.000.000:00000`

(Obviously, replace `000.000.000.000:00000` with an IP of your choice)

Answer (score 3):

I think this may have changed since the question was originally asked. Here's how you connect now.
`client.connect [IP Address]:[Port (default: 28015)]`

Example: `client.connect 127.0.0.1:28015`

Answer (score 0):

Well now it just works with `connect [IP Address]:[Port (default: 28015)]`

Example: `connect 127.0.0.1:28015`